# How to correctly use `JSON_TABLE` to fetch matching names from Json Array within MySQL8?

Tags: mysql, json, join, left-join

I am using `MySQL 8` and my table structure looks as below:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT, `group` VARCHAR(255), names JSON);
```

I am able to correctly insert records using the following `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
(3001, 'group1', '[{"name": "name1", "type": "user"}, {"name": "name2", "type": "user"}, {"name": "techDept", "type": "dept"}]'),
(3002, 'group2', '[{"name": "name1", "type": "user"}]');
```

The JSON format has two types - `user` and `dept`

I want to fetch all `groups` having a matching name to the `name1` from Json Array and I have written following query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t1, JSON_TABLE(users, "$.users[*].type" COLUMNS(f INT PATH '$')) as user WHERE user.name = 'name1'
```

I am getting below error:

```
Unknown column name
```

Desired Output:

```
group1
group2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested on 8.0.23 using your data:

```
SELECT t1.`group` 
FROM t1, JSON_TABLE(names, '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS(
      name TEXT PATH '$.name', 
      type TEXT PATH '$.type')
    ) AS j 
WHERE j.name = 'name1'
```

Output:

```
+--------+
| group  |
+--------+
| group1 |
| group2 |
+--------+
```

Comment: If you have this much trouble using the JSON functions, I strongly suggest you use MySQL in the normal fashion, with data elements in individual rows and columns.